# Adjacency matrix from TopoJSON

Tags: topojson, adjacency

I have a TopoJSON file which describes electoral districts in Montreal, and I would like to produce an adjacency matrix which would tell me which districts share a boundary with which other districts. Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: here is the file https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/mtlelection2013bydistrict/blob/master/districts.topojson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get raw adjacency information as a side-effect of the [`topojson.mesh`](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#mesh) and [`topojson.meshArcs`](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#meshArcs) functions (assuming you like JavaScript).  The optional third parameter to those is a function that will be called (perhaps repeatedly) for adjacent geometries.  Here's some nodejs pseudo-code:

```js
var topojson = require('topojson');
var fs = require('fs');
var inputTopology = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( ... ));
var objectOfInterest = inputTopology.objects.alldistricts;

topojson.meshArcs(inputTopology, objectOfInterest, function(distA, distB) {
    console.log(distA.properties.Name + " and " +
        distB.properties.Name + " are adjacent!");
});
```

It doesn't produce a real matrix, but that could be done with a little bit of extra code inside that function.

And note that the function will be called for each arc in the topology, so you'll get calls where `distA` and `distB` are the same object (when an arc is "exterior"), and you'll potentially get multiple calls for the same `distA` and `distB` if one of their shared edges is made up of multiple arcs.